# perf_event with openMP

Tags: openmp, performancecounter, perf

I'm using perf_event to measure performance information. I confirmed that instruction counter is working well in a single core.
However, when I try to use parallel computing with a openMP, the result seemed something wrong..
I thought if number of cores is changed, the instruction counter is same.

```
for(int i=1; i<=8; i++)
{
      cnt=0;
      omp_set_num_threads(i);

      ioctl(pc_c, PERF_EVENT_IOC_RESET, 0);
      ioctl(pc_c, PERF_EVENT_IOC_ENABLE, 0);

      #pragma omp parallel for
      for(int tid = 0; tid < 1000000; tid++)
      {
          //sleep(0.2);
          cnt ++;
      }

      ioctl(pc_c, PERF_EVENT_IOC_DISABLE, 0);
      read(pc_c, &pc_c_result, sizeof(long long));
}
```

when I use sleep(0.2), the result seemed regular.

```
// result
core[1] perf count      = 25006756
core[2] perf count      = 14681730
core[3] perf count      = 10166403
core[4] perf count      = 7601514
core[5] perf count      = 7165846
core[6] perf count      = 4202816
core[7] perf count      = 3621566
core[8] perf count      = 3247411
```

I understood this result is about one core. So, this result is correct. 
But, when I use cnt++ instead of sleep function, result was totally different.

```
core[1] perf count      = 5735
core[2] perf count      = 74244
core[3] perf count      = 57295
core[4] perf count      = 2976047
core[5] perf count      = 35821
core[6] perf count      = 2112339
core[7] perf count      = 10487
core[8] perf count      = 3885038
```

I can't find any rule about this result.
Isn't there anyone who know about this?

I referred to this site
http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/perf_event_open.2.html#EXAMPLE

Comment: What makes you believe that `cnt++` isn't removed by the compiler since it doesn't do a thing? I'm pretty sure that the compiler optimises and removes the entire loop altogether.

Comment: oh my god... you are right. I didn't think about optimization. thank you.

Comment: I completely disagree that your results seem regular in the first case. perf_event do not count events if the thread is blocked, which does  the sleep call. BTW, I think you need perf_event handler per thread instead of a single handler for every thread.